# Получить количество строк одной модели, ссылающихся на объект другой модели в Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-model

Существует две модели: Articles и Views - Статьи и просмотры статей соответственно.

В модели Views есть поле article, ссылающееся через models.ForeignKey на объект модели Article.
Мне необходимо получить список всех статей, отсортированный по количеству просмотров.

Пытался делать так:

```py
Articles.objects.filter(status="published").order_by("views.count"):
```

но views.count не определяется.
Ещё нужно сделать тоже самое, только для просмотров за последнюю неделю, то есть удовлетворяющих фильтру

```py
view_datetime__gte=(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Как вариант решения я придумал создать двумерный список, в котором будут перебираться все статьи, отсортированные по чему угодно, каждой из которых сопоставляется её количество просмотров за всё время и за неделю, вроде такого:

```py
[
[Article0, 78, 13]
[Article1, 96, 7]
[Article2, 48, 21]
[Article3, 456, 122]
]
```

Откуда отсортировать статьи по количеству просмотров проблем не составит, но есть стойкое ощущение, что возможна более простая реализация.

Comment: через [агрегацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) не пробовали? как-то так, например: articles = Articles.objects.annotate(count=Count('views_set__id')).order_by('count')

Comment: @Jack_oS, Для общего числа просмотров получилось, спасибо. А можно то же самое сделать для просмотров за последнюю неделю, то есть применить фильтр к методам Count, Sum, Avg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [@Jack_oS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/420098/jack-os) за подсказку с агрегацией.

Для получения статей, отсортированных по количеству просмотров за всё время мы достаточно просто можем использовать обычный метод Count внутри annotate:

```py
from django.db.models import Count
...

poparts = Articles.objects.annotate(views_num=Count('views__id')).order_by('-views_num')
```

В моём случае у каждого просмотра есть свой вес (это нужно для ручного добавления или убавления просмотров администраторами), поэтому код будет следующим:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum
...

poparts = Articles.objects.annotate(views_num=Sum('views__view_weight')).order_by('-views_num')
```

Для сортировки по просмотрам, полученным исключительно за последнюю неделю, мы можем применить фильтр прямо к QuerySet'у объектов модели Articles, и получить вот такую вот штуку:

```py
poparts = Articles.objects.filter(
        views__view_datetime__gte=(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-7)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    ).annotate(views_num=Sum('views__view_weight')).order_by('-views_num')
```